# Creating a button based on values in array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

So basically, I made an **empty** array with JS, which is filled in dynamically based on user choice. Now, I would like a button to appear based on weather or not a value is stored inside the array. And I can't seem to do that, even though a required value is inside the array. Both array and button creation are the part of the same script, if such information makes difference.
My code is something like this:

```
array = [];
//somewhere along the way it get's filled up...
//...
if (array.indexOf("anItem") == true){
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = "Text";
btn.setAttribute('id', 'button2');
paragra.appendChild(btn);
}
```

What am I doing wrong and is there hope for me?

Comment: from this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf indexOf doesnt return a boolean, but a -1 if false. that might be the first issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line from

```
if (array.indexOf("anItem") == true){
```

to

```
if (array.indexOf("anItem") != -1){
```

and let us know if there are any other problems. indexOf() returns the position of your value within the array, or -1 if it can't find it.

Comment: I tested it only a bit, but it seems to fix my issue. It didn't occur to me that the return value of indexOf is it not true/false. I will test it further later on. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This will work :-

```
array = [];

if(array.indexOf("anItem") != -1){
  //Item available
}else{
  // Item not available
}
```

`indexOf` returns the index of an Item in an array and if the Item is not found, it returns `-1`. The above code checks whether the `indexOf("anItem")` returns `-1` or not.

**Edit**

BTW, a method named `includes()` is a part of ECMAScript 7. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). However, ECMAScript 7 lacks browser support.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, it was very helpful. I will check out includes() method you mentioned, despite it's inflexibility.